# How to resolve recursion error in python django urls.py

Tags: django, amazon-s3, python-3.7

I'm pretty new to django and working on a project from https://github.com/mkaykisiz/DjangoS3Browser/ where I'm ending up with recursion error after adding "url(r'^' + settings.S3_BROWSER_SETTINGS + '/', include('djangoS3Browser.s3_browser.urls'))," line to url.py

Project structure:
I've the views under s3_browser dir and hence imported the same Can you correct me?Below is my project structure:

```
└───djangoS3Browser

    └───manage.py

    ├───s3_browser

    │   └───__pycache__

        └─── operations.py

                                └─── settings.py

                                └─── urls.py

                                └─── views.py

                                └─── wsgi.py

    ├───static

    │   ├───css

    │   ├───images

    │   └───js

    ├───templates

    ├───templatetags
```

URL.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from djangoS3Browser.s3_browser import settings
from djangoS3Browser.s3_browser import views
import sys

urlpatterns = [
                  url(r'^get_folder_items/(.+)/(.+)/$', views.get_folder_items, name='get_folder_items'),
                  url(r'^upload/$', views.upload, name='upload'),
                  url(r'^create_folder/$', views.create_folder, name='create_folder'),
                  url(r'^download/$', views.download, name='download'),
                  url(r'^rename_file/$', views.rename_file, name='rename_file'),
                  url(r'^paste_file/$', views.paste_file, name='paste_file'),
                  url(r'^move_file/$', views.move_file, name='move_file'),
                  url(r'^delete_file/$', views.delete_file, name='delete_file'),
                  url(r'^' + settings.S3_BROWSER_SETTINGS + '/', include('djangoS3Browser.s3_browser.urls')),
              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Settings.py:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ""
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ""
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = ""
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = ""
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
S3_BROWSER_SETTINGS = "djangoS3Browser"

AWS_EXPIRY = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
control = 'max-age=%d, s-maxage=%d, must-revalidate' % (AWS_EXPIRY, AWS_EXPIRY)
AWS_HEADERS = {'Cache-Control': bytes(control, encoding='latin-1')}

TEMPLATES = [
    { 
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': 
    {
    'libraries': {'s3-load': 'djangoS3Browser.templatetags.s3-tags',},
    'context_processors': ["django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',]
    }
    }
]
SECRET_KEY = 'y130-j9oz4r5aoamn_n=+s-*7n)*3^s$jmf4(qw6ik28()g^(n'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
ROOT_URLCONF= 'djangoS3Browser.s3_browser.urls'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
STATIC_URL = '{}/static/'.format(AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL)
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djangoS3Browser',
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoS3Browser.s3_browser.wsgi.application'
MIDDLEWARE = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Actual result:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 162, in check
    warnings.extend(self._check_pattern_startswith_slash())
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 125, in _check_pattern_startswith_slash
    if regex_pattern.startswith(('/', '^/', '^\\/')) and not regex_pattern.endswith('/'):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing wrong settings and views file. Just modify your code like:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from your_app import views
import sys

urlpatterns = [
                  url(r'^get_folder_items/(.+)/(.+)/$', views.get_folder_items, name='get_folder_items'),
                  url(r'^upload/$', views.upload, name='upload'),
                  url(r'^create_folder/$', views.create_folder, name='create_folder'),
                  url(r'^download/$', views.download, name='download'),
                  url(r'^rename_file/$', views.rename_file, name='rename_file'),
                  url(r'^paste_file/$', views.paste_file, name='paste_file'),
                  url(r'^move_file/$', views.move_file, name='move_file'),
                  url(r'^delete_file/$', views.delete_file, name='delete_file'),
                  url(r'^' + settings.S3_BROWSER_SETTINGS + '/', include('djangoS3Browser.s3_browser.urls')),
              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**EDIT:** Instead of copying to your workspace, you need to install djangoS3Browser via pip and add it to your *existing* project. As in their github repo:

> Just add as an application to a Django project, add some settings, and you'll be able to browse cloud containers and implied subdirectories, as well as view / download objects.

So you need to create a project in django by using `django-admin startproject mysite` command, then import djangoS3Browser as an app.

Comment: I'm seeing below error after importing patterns...

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoS3Browser.s3_browser.urls.urlpatterns'; 'djangoS3Browser.s3_browser.urls' is not a package

Comment: Thank you..Updated urls.py with your code but I’m still ending up with recursion error:

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver

    return check_method()

  if regex_pattern.startswith(('/', '^/', '^\\/')) and not regex_pattern.endswith('/'):

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: You also import the wrong views package. You should import your own.

Comment: I've the views under s3_browser dir and hence imported the same  Can you correct me?Below is my project structure:

'''└───djangoS3Browser

    └───manage.py

    ├───s3_browser

    │   └───__pycache__

        └─── operations.py

                                └─── settings.py

                                └─── urls.py

                                └─── views.py

                                └─── wsgi.py

    ├───static

    │   ├───css

    │   ├───images

    │   └───js

    ├───templates

    ├───templatetags'''

Comment: Please update your question and add these in the question.

Comment: Why do you copy djangoS3Browser under your workspace instead of installing it via pip?

Comment: I just download the copy from github and extracted the same.

Comment: If you dont have a good reason for it, do not copy the whole library, install it from pip and follow the steps in that library's guideline.

Comment: Ok Thank you Cagrias for the help, But after installing via pip I don't see the manage.py file in the directory...Do we need to create one or how do we run if manage.py is not required?